# Using iptables to DROP UDP Multicast Traffic

Tags: iptables

My application listens to a stream of data that is broadcast using UDP. I would like to simulate a network outage by interrupting the UDP traffic on my server.

In order to achieve this I have attempted to run the following `iptables` command to block all incoming traffic on address `239.255.52.123` port `35912`

```
/sbin/iptables --insert INPUT --protocol udp --source 239.255.52.123/24 --sport 35912 --verbose --jump DROP -m comment --comment 'Emergency Drop'
```

This does not appear to be working a simple netcat listening to this address continues to receive data after executing the `iptables` command

Comment: You mixed up source and destination. `iptables -I INPUT -p udp -d 239.255.52.123 --dport 35912  -j DROP` should work.

Answer (score 2):

As per @lenniey's comment, there is a mixup in the original command between the source and destination address/port.

The multicast address should be specified as the destination:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p udp -d 239.255.52.123 --dport 35912  -j DROP
```